# CAS gradle overlay with non self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cas, jasig

I'm using CAS using the gradle overlay method. I am able to use it with a self signed certificate. However, when I try to use a certificate from the FreeIPA certificate authority, I am getting the following error message:

```
2018-02-03 13:39:54,298 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService] - <Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]>
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.24.jar!/:8.5.24]
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Alias name [null] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:116) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.24.jar!/:8.5.24]
```

I have added the FreeIPA CA certificate to /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/security/cacerts

And, put the certificate into /etc/cas/thekeystore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -keyout cas.key -out cas.csr
```

[Send CSR to certificate authority]

[Download CA certificate PEM file]

[Download CAS certificate PEM file]

```
cp cas.key /etc/pki/tls/private/.
cp cas.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/.
cp freeipa_ca.crt  /etc/pki/tls/certs/.
cat cas.pem freeipa_ca.pem > cas_all.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey /etc/pki/tls/private/cas.key -in cas_all.pem  -name cas -out cas.p12
keytool -delete -alias cas -keystore /etc/cas/thekeystore
keytool -list  -keystore /etc/cas/thekeystore -v
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cas.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore /etc/cas/thekeystore
```